# What is the difference between pointer and array in the following context?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, strcpy

```
#include <cstring>
int main()
    {
    char *pName = new char[10];
    char dummy[] = "dummy";
    strcpy(pName + 0,dummy);//how this is different from -->this works
    strcpy(pName[0],dummy);//this one...--> error C2664: 'strcpy' : 
                           //cannot convert parameter 1 
                           //from 'char' to 'char *'

    }
```

Comment: I think you mean strcpy(&(pName[0]), dummy);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- pName[0] is the first element in a character array (**one** character)
- pName is a shortcut to &pName[0] (a pointer to the first element of your array)

The reason you are getting your error is because strcpy expects a pointer to a char (char*), and not a char value (which is what pName[0] is)

Comment: so [] operator on pointer does 2 things dereference and addition?

Comment: @yesraaj: Yes. pName[5] is the same thing as *(pName + 5).

Comment: yesraaj: arrayPointer[1] is the same as *(arrayPointer + 1). The latter is "increment pointer so that it points to item at position 1 in the array, then dereference to get value pointed to".

Comment: +1, Pushing toward "nice answer" badget :) This is correct for pName. One note from silly litb: The same does not hold true for dummy in all cases: "dummy" is not a shortcut for "&dummy[0]".

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with pointers and arrays in C or C++ it really helps to recognize them as very distinct constructs (I think one of the best books that explains this distinction is a book called "Deep C Secrets" if i remember correctly).  What muddies the waters is the fact that there is a one way silent conversion allowed from array-names to pointers (an inconsistency in the language's handling of variable names) - but it is very important not to interpret the existence of this decay phenomenon as implying equivalence.

To help us reason about this, let us introduce the idea of a 'memory cell'.  We model a 'memory cell' as having two attributes:

```
a) value
b) address
```

We can then model a simple C++ variable as having two attributes (we do not need types at this low level of abstraction):

```
c) name  
d) memory cell
```

Like most models, it has some deficiencies (does not deal with an array with more than one element, but it is sufficient for our purposes).

So for example:

```
// non-array variable: name 'i', and memory cell: value=3, address=0x0A
int i = 3;

// non-array variable: name 'p', and memory cell: value=0x0A, address=0x0B
int *p = &i;

// array variable: name 'a', and memory cell: vale=4, address=0x0C     
int a[1] = { 4 };

// non-array variable: name 'b', and memory cell: value=0x0C, address = 0x0D
int (*b)[1] = &a;

// non-array variable: name 's', and memory cell: value=0x0C, address = 0x0E
int *s = &a[0];


// non-array variable: name 't', and memory cell: value=0x0C, address = 0x0F
int *t = a; // Here is the key difference! read on...
```

Now here's the main difference between an array variable and a non-array (pointer) C++ variable:

> When a variable name in C++ is evaluated, it always evaluates to the value of its memory cell with one exception: if the variable names an array variable.
>     If the variable is the name of an array it evaluates to the *address* of the memory cell.
>     The above two lines are worth reading again.

Here are some examples to help clarify the implications (refer to the above variables):

```
int k = i;  // the 'i' name evaluates to the value of its cell, so 'k' is set to 3

int *q = p; // 'p' evaluates to the value of its cell, so 'q' is set to 0x0A

int *r = a; // 'a' evaluates to the *address* of its cell, so 'r' is set to 0x0C

int (*c)[1] = b; // 'c' is set to 0x0D
```

This in no way should imply that an array variable is the *same* as a pointer variable.
They have inherently different types and any attempt to treat them as the *same* (i.e. define a variable name as an array in one translation unit, and as a pointer in another) will result in bad things happening.

So for e.g. do not do this:

```
// myproj_file1.cpp
int array[100] = { 0 }; // here 'array' evaluates to the *address* of the first memory cell

// myproj_file2.cpp
extern int* array; // here 'array' evaluates to the *value* of the first memory cell 
            // Assuming the linker links the two
            // what it does if you read the assembly, is something like this: 
            // extern int* array = (int*) array[0];
            // but it doesn't have to, it can do anything, since the behavior is undefined
```

I hope this helps.
If you still feel that further clarification might help, please ask a followup question, and don't hesitate to get a copy (library?) of that "Deep C Secrets" book :)

--
p.s. function types and their names and their decay are irrelevant to most of this post
p.s. I have also intentionally left out that the array-to-pointer conversion does not occur when arrays are bound to reference types

Comment: +1, nice one. i think your definition of "variable" matches the one of C++, too, which says: "A variable is introduced by the declaration of an object. The variable’s name denotes the object." These are the two properties of a variable that you define: name, and memory cell (object == region of storage with associated properties (type, storage duration, is-alive, ...), memory cell = start of that region).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.  They will both crash since you've not allocated any space for pName. :)[EDIT: No longer a crash - question has been edited]

The main difference is a stylistic one, frequently influenced by which fits the way the surrounding code is written - mostly array access or mostly pointer access.

(EDIT: assuming you really meant &pName[0] as Brian Bondy pointed out.)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, `strcpy(pName[0], dummy);` isn't correct. Even if memory was allocated for it.

This is because `pName[0]` is of type 'char' whilst `pName + 0` is of type char*. They both reference the same memory, but in different ways.

The compiler can then turn `strcpy(pName[0], dummy);` into `strcpy((char*) pName[0], dummy);` which is a dangerous implicit cast. If your compiler is half decent you'll get a warning or error (As you are seeing with your "error C2664").

Answer (score 0):

An array is simply a pointer automatically (usually) assigned to an automatically allocated block of memory. Taking your example, you can declare dummy equally as:

```
char    dummy[] = "dummy";
char    *dummy = "dummy";
```

And you can then use either array syntax or pointer syntax to access the data:

```
char    ch = dummy[0];   // get the first element of the array
char    ch = *dummy;     // get the data pointed to by dummy
```

Both `[]` and `*` can be used de re-reference pointers and arrays, so the following are equivalent:

```
array[N];
*(ptr + N);
```

Given the second form, `(ptr + N)` is still a pointer, just further along the array. This is why it is syntactically correct in your example. `ptr[N]` is a de-referencing of the pointer and is a char (in this context).

Answer (score 0):

pName is pointer to newly allocated memory. `char *pName = new char[10];`

dummy is also an array/pointer.   `char dummy[] = "dummy";`

pName is pointer and pointing to base address, even you add (pName + 0) is still pointing to same memory location, becuase your only adding 0.    `strcpy(pName + 0,dummy);`

strcpy use pointer variable, and your passing value in first argument, therefore your are getting error     `strcpy(pName[0],dummy)`